# Mounting hard disk

Tags: mount

I have made a bootable usb with rufus.
Inside the usb it has the ubuntu20.04 installation.
When i click try ubuntu everything is ok.

How can i mount the hard drive, to copy the files in another usb disk?

What can i do when

```
mount: /tmp: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.
```

Comment: You can not "mount a hard drive". Try to mount a partition, like /dev/sda1 instead, and don't use /tmp as a mount point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `lsblk` in terminal. You can see something like that:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop1    7:1    0    69M  1 loop /snap/lxd/14804
loop2    7:2    0  27.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/7264
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part /media/usbdisk
```

Next, for mount, you should type:

```
sudo mkdir /media/usbstick
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/usbstick
```

If filesystem is NTFS (not vfat as in my case) then try

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/usbstick
```